# Transfer files from git to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: git, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

Is there any way we can upload files in git directly to the google cloud storage bucket?

I have tried using the below command:

```
gsutil cp https://Link.git gs://bucketname
```

But it gives me an error as:

> InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme "https".

Is there any other way that I can upload content to this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Peeking under the hood shows, in `google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/storage_url.py`, the (likely) trigger for the error message you got:

```
def _GetSchemeFromUrlString(url_str):
  """Returns scheme component of a URL string."""

  end_scheme_idx = url_str.find('://')
  if end_scheme_idx == -1:
    # File is the default scheme.
    return 'file'
  else:
    return url_str[0:end_scheme_idx].lower()
```

[...]

```
def StorageUrlFromString(url_str):
  """Static factory function for creating a StorageUrl from a string."""

  scheme = _GetSchemeFromUrlString(url_str)

  if scheme not in ('file', 's3', 'gs'):
    raise InvalidUrlError('Unrecognized scheme "%s"' % scheme)
```

Basically the tool doesn't have support for generic URLs.

Of course - one could venture into enhancing the tool to actually support direct copy from a git repo. But it should be noted that it will only work in daisychain mode. From [Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options):

> -D
>
> Copy in "daisy chain" mode, i.e., copying between two buckets by
>   hooking a download to an upload, via the machine where gsutil is run.
>   This stands in contrast to the default, where data are copied between
>   two buckets "in the cloud", i.e., without needing to copy via the
>   machine where gsutil runs.
>
> [...]
>
> Note: Daisy chain mode is automatically used when copying between
>   providers (e.g., to copy data from Google Cloud Storage to another
>   provider).

But since in such case the data would have to pass through the local machine running `gsutil` it is probably simpler to just clone the git repo locally and then use the unmodified `gsutil` to upload from that local repo to the bucket :)